# F# Script to read file line by line and add string to each line

Tags: text, f#

Let's say I have this txt file:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
ch
```

To each line I want to add `,3` and then I want to add character accord to number of line. To first line add `,k` to second line add `,r` and to the third add `,p` and this repeat until the end.

So the result would be this:

```
a,k,3
b,r,3
c,p,3
d,k,3
e,r,3
f,p,3
g,k,3
h,p,3
ch,r,3
```

I have this for iterating lines:

```
open System.IO

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    File.ReadLines(argv.[0]) |> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")
    0
```

but it still doesn't work (it's not printing lines). I am running this in `cmd.exe` by `fsi script.fsx namefile.txt`.

I am noob in F# but I want to start learning it. Just now I need this script. So If anyone can post me right solution thanks.

**Edit:**
Thanks to John Palmer I have now this:

```
open System.IO

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    File.ReadLines(argv.[1]) |> Seq.iteri (fun i x -> match i % 3 with
                                                                 | 0 -> printfn "%s,k,3" x
                                                                 | 1 -> printfn "%s,r,3" x
                                                                 | 2 -> printfn "%s,p,3" x
                                                                 | _ -> printfn "%s" x)
    0
```

Looks good but still nothing is printing at command window and nothing happens with original file. So little help with writing changes to file (it doesn't matter if to new file or to old one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first entry in `argv` is the executable name.  As a result, you probably want to use `argv.[1]` rather than `argv.[0]` to get the first argument to the function.

For your second problem, you want to do something like

```
Seq.iteri (fun i x -> match i % 3 with
                      | 0 -> printfn "%s,k,3" x
                      //other cases similar
```

**EDIT** (for updated question)

If you are seeing nothing printed, I would guess you have the wrong file path - perhaps add something like

```
printfn "%s" (argv.[1])
```

to ensure you are opening the correct file.

If you want to output to a file you need to do something like

```
use file = System.IO.File.CreateText("Some file name)
File.ReadLines(argv.[1]) 
|> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> match i%3 with |0 -> fprintfn ...) //note fprintfn instead of printfn
```

As `fprintf` will output to a file.

However, I would check you are opening the correct file first

Comment: I have edited my question with my new solution. I am just not yet finished.

Comment: @Bibo - also try adding `System.Console.Read() |> ignore` to stop your app closing early so you can check what is printed.

Answer (score 1):

Your entry point wont automatically run when using `fsi`, your code would work if you compiled using `fsc`. If you change it to something like this you can run it via `fsi`.

```
open System.IO

let main (argv:string[]) =
    File.ReadLines(argv.[1]) |> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")
    0

main fsi.CommandLineArgs
```

Note, as John Palmer suggested you will need to use `argv.[1]` as `fsi.CommandLineArgs` includes the name of the script in the arguments.

Alternatively you could setup your scripts to work as a script and as a source file using something like this [link](http://fssnip.net/V). Here is a simplifed version of that applied to your script

```
open System.IO

#if COMPILED
[<EntryPoint>]
#endif
let main (argv:string[]) =
    File.ReadLines(argv.[0]) |> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")
    0

#if INTERACTIVE
fsi.CommandLineArgs |> Seq.skip 1 |> Seq.toArray |> main
#endif
```

You can run this in two ways:

1. As a script

   `fsi.exe script.fsx -- input.txt`
2. Or compile it and run the executable

   `fsc.exe script.fsx`
   `script.exe input.txt`